# Return objects from nested functions?

Tags: javascript, function, object, angularjs

I am trying to return objects inside of a function as an object inside of another function:

```
    function () {
    // body...
var dailyPrice = null; 
                function fun1(xml) {
                /***function**/
                }

                function fun2(xml) {
                /*function***/
                }
                function getRate(source, $scope) {
                    var dateValue = $("Date", source).text() || "";
                    if (!dateValue) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    var dailyPrice = $("DailyPrice", source).text() || "";
                    var weeklyPrice = $("WeeklyPrice", source).text() || "";
                    var monthlyPrice = $("MonthlyPrice", source).text() || "";
                    var isAvailable = $("IsAvailable", source).text() === "1";
                    var minimumStay = Number($("MinimumStay", source).text());
                    if (isNaN(minimumStay)) {
                        minimumStay = DEFAULT_MINIMUM_STAY;
                    }

                    return {
                        date: new Date(dateValue),
                        dailyPrice: dailyPrice,
                        weeklyPrice: weeklyPrice,
                        monthlyPrice: monthlyPrice,
                        reserved: !isAvailable,
                        minimumStay: minimumStay
                    };

                }
               return {
                    getallrates: function(source, $scope){
                        getRate(source, $scope);
                        console.log(getRate.dailyPrice);
                    },
                    init: function(xml) {
                        parseXml(xml);
                    },
                }
}
```

now when i run getallrates(); it returns undefined why?? 
I have also tried the following returns:

```
getallrates: function(source, $scope){
                    var allrates =  getRate();
                    var getdailyprice = allrates.dailyPrice;
                    console.log(getdailyprice);
                },
```

Comment: looks like you are missing a `return` on `return getRate(source, $scope)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to this:

```
return {
                    getallrates: function(source, $scope){
                        return getRate(source, $scope);                            
                    },
                    init: function(xml) {
                        parseXml(xml);
                    },
                }
```

Comment: ok so how do i get at daily price from the parent function of this one??

Comment: You are returning it from the getRate function, so it sould be as simple as calling: `var rates = getAllRates(source, $scope); console.log(rates.dailyPrice);`

Comment: this still isn't returning i think it's because i'm trying to retrive it from a service in a module controller in angularJS, this is driving me up the wall.

Comment: Take it out of angular into a seperate, pure JS file, and try it, if it works then it's angular problem