# how to retrive var's from nested functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript

ok consider the following:

```
function(){
  function getRate(source, scope) {
    var dateValue = $("Date", source).text() || "";
    if (!dateValue) {
      return null;
    }
    var d = new Date();
    var dailyPrice = $("DailyPrice", source).text() || "";
    var weeklyPrice = $("WeeklyPrice", source).text() || "";
    var monthlyPrice = $("MonthlyPrice", source).text() || "";
    var isAvailable = $("IsAvailable", source).text() === "1";
    var minimumStay = Number($("MinimumStay", source).text());

    return {
      date: new Date(dateValue),
      dailyPrice: dailyPrice,
      weeklyPrice: weeklyPrice,
      monthlyPrice: monthlyPrice,
      reserved: !isAvailable,
      minimumStay: minimumStay
    };
  }

  return {
    getRates: function(xml){
      return getRates(xml);
    },
    getAllRates: function(source, scope){
      return new getRate();
    },
  };
}
```

How do i get at dailyPrice from outside of this function I have tried the following but it returns null

```
var getitall = getAllRates();
```

When i run it through the debugger it gets to the function but allways returns the value as null. 
why?

Comment: Can you make a more complete example, maybe a fiddle ?This code looks confused. Why are you returning something from a function you seem to treat as a constructor ?

Comment: @dystroy here's the fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/SmwNP/

Comment: @vimes1984 it doesn't contain your code...

Comment: What does this have to do with "arrays"? Also, the point of supplying a link to jsfiddle is to have a demonstration of the relevant part of your code so that we can see the error or incorrect behaviour for ourselves and play around with it a bit. An 1100 line block of JS that doesn't seem to include the same code as shown in your question really doesn't help at all.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is no help at all.

Comment: Your `getAllRates` is not passing the `source` and `scope` params to the `getRate` function (which doesn't need `new` in front of it, btw).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return objects from nested functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043241/return-objects-from-nested-functions)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SmwNP/2/

Comment: @vimes1984: Where in the example is the code from the question?  Where is the issue?

Comment: @RocketHazmat the call to the console.log is at line 33 - 34 this then calls line 1076 which in turn calls line 869 which is where i'm defining the dailyPrice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what exactly you're trying to accomplish. But, try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/SmwNP/4/

```
var FooBar = (function() {
    function getRate(source, scope) {
        var dateValue = $("Date", source).text() || "";
        if (!dateValue) { return null; }
        var d = new Date();
        var dailyPrice = $("DailyPrice", source).text() || "";
        var weeklyPrice = $("WeeklyPrice", source).text() || "";
        var monthlyPrice = $("MonthlyPrice", source).text() || "";
        var isAvailable = $("IsAvailable", source).text() === "1";
        var minimumStay = Number($("MinimumStay", source).text());
        return {
            date: new Date(dateValue),
            dailyPrice: dailyPrice,
            weeklyPrice: weeklyPrice,
            monthlyPrice: monthlyPrice,
            reserved: !isAvailable,
            minimumStay: minimumStay
        };
    }
    return {
        getRates: function(xml) {
            console.log('executing getRates');
            //return getRates(xml);//where is there a getRates() function?
        },
        getAllRates: function(source, scope){
            console.log('executing getAllRates');
            return getRate(source, scope);
        }
    };
});

var something = FooBar();
something.getRates('z');
something.getAllRates('x', 'y');
```

At the very least, this exposes `getAllRates` for use.

Comment: I don't think you need the `new` there.

Comment: If you're talking about the `new FooBar`, I think the `new` is required. At least, the code breaks if you do not use `new`.

Comment: You're returning an object from `FooBar`, so you can just do `var something = FooBar();`

Comment: ok so how do i get at the returned object?

Comment: @Rocket: You will get an error if you use parens ().  FooBar is not a function, it is an object {}.  You literally need nothing more than `var something = FooBar;`.  In actual fact, that is superfluous as well.  You just need to reference FooBar directly: `alert(FooBar.getAllRates('something', 'something else').dailyRate);`

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, you're correct.

Comment: @vimes1984: `FooBar.getAllRates('something', 'something else').dailyRate`

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SmwNP/5/ As pointed out in @Craig's comment, you access the variables by `something.getAllRates().dailyPrice` Or, you can bypass creating the `something` variable, and do this `FooBar().getAllRates('x', 'y').dailyPrice`

Comment: they still come up null....

Comment: The code posted here works. If they're coming up `null`, then the problem is elsewhere. Are you sure the variables are receiving values? Have you checked that the functions all execute as expected (not trying to access them outside of themselves)? You may need to post more related code.

Answer (score 1):

```
getAllRates: function(source, scope){
  return new getRate();
}
```

Your error is in this code.  You need to pass the `source` and `scope` along to the `getRate` function.  Without those parameters, `$("Date", source).text()` will find nothing, therefore the function returns `null`, because you told it to.

```
if (!dateValue) {
  return null;
}
```

---

To fix it, you need to change your code to this:

```
getAllRates: function(source, scope){
  return getRate(source, scope);  // getRate needs to be passed the parameters
}
```

Comment: ok after adding this i still get null back , i've been going around like this all morning.

Comment: What is `source`?  What does `console.log(source)` show?  P.S. `$("Date", source)` will select `<Date>` elements.  Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: source is the source of my xml file, all this function does is return the strings from my xml and dump them, hence the horrible .each function inside of getRate where is compares a scope of the div date-cell and appends the dailyprice is it's the same...

Comment: Also, line 33. `var dumpitall = booking.getAllRates(null,scope);`  Why are you passing `null`?  Shouldn't you be passing something to search in?  `$("Date", source)` can't find anything if you don't send it something to look in :-P